# flatten array of dictionaries with duplicate values Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I have an Array of dictionaries like this :

```
let arrayofDictionaries:[[String:Any]] = [
    ["nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 327, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:52", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 45000, "bookName": "آموزش عربي انساني نکته ها"],
    ["nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 366, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:58", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 19000, "bookName": "آبي عربي پيش1و2انساني"],
    ["nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 327, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:52", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 45000, "bookName": "آموزش عربي انساني نکته ها"],
    ["nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 366, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:58", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 19000, "bookName": "آبي عربي پيش1و2انساني"],
]
```

The Dictionary inside the array has fixed keys which values would change. 
I tried this code:

```
for item in arrayofDictionaries {
    for (kind, value) in item {
        print(kind)
        dic.updateValue(value!, forKey: kind)
    }    
}
```

but this would eliminate duplicate kies and just return the last values.
the output of the above code would be:

```
dic = ["nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 366, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:58", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 19000, "bookName": "آبي عربي پيش1و2انساني"]
```

what i want is a dictionary like this:

```
let flattenedArray : [String : Any] = [
    "nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 327, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:52", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 45000, "bookName": "آموزش عربي انساني نکته ها",
    "nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 366, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:58", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 19000, "bookName": "آبي عربي پيش1و2انساني",
    "nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 327, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:52", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 45000, "bookName": "آموزش عربي انساني نکته ها",
    "nationalCode": "1570158037", "bookId": 366, "orderDate": "2017-07-24 14:11:58", "mobileNo": "09873456789", "isFavorite": false, "price": 19000, "bookName": "آبي عربي پيش1و2انساني",
]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: "what i want is a dictionary like this" - you can't have a dictionary like this, period. Dictionary's keys are unique and each refers to a single value. What are you trying to achieve with dictionary like this?

Comment: as @mag_zbc said, "What are you trying to achieve?", we can suggest you alternatives.

Comment: @mag_zbc I'm trying to do a post request. it should turn to a string.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it should turn to a string"? Give an example of your post request.

Comment: this is what my the web service needed POST /newsite/Common/WebService/WSPublicApp.asmx/InsertFactor HTTP/1.1
Host: city.kanoon.ir
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

FactorInfo=string
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string> . and i should post a string for requesting i suppose. and i want that arrayofDictionaries alter to a string so i can do the post reques. i'm new to this posting stuff sorry for Unclearity.

Comment: You are trying to post to a SOAP Service. Which renders your dictionary least of your problems. You need to post a correctly built XML string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JsoonFactor, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        let jr = (jsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .regularExpression))!
        let jrrr = jr.removingWhitespaces()
        let urlEncodedJson = jrrr.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments we finally get what are you trying to do - you want to turn your `arrayOfDictionaries` to a `String` to post it with a request.

It may vary depending on how exactly you want it to look, but if you want to turn your `arrayOfDictionaries` to string, you can do something like this

```
var aString : String = ""
for aBook in arrayOfDictionaries {
    if let nationalCode = aBook["nationalCode"] {
        aString.append("nationalCode : " + nationalCode + ", ")
    }
    if let bookId = aBook["bookId"] {
        aString.append("bookId : " + bookId + ", ")
    }
    // and so on, and so forth
}
```

Why do it manually, instead of just iterating with `(key, value)` over the dictionary? Unfortunately, due to the fact that `Dictionary` is implemented as hash map, there is no guarantee that when iterating your keys will appear in the same order they were when you declared the dictionary (actually, it's almost guaranteed that the order will be different).

But again, it's the matter of format your string needs to have. If the order doesn't matter, just iterate with `(key, value)`

Comment: I need exactly the format in flattenedArray. the output of this code doesn't have brackets or double coats

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are meant to be used with unique keys, it is probable that the process is not eliminating the duplicate keys but the creation itself, the dictionary class even has a function to create a dictionary defining the rules to decide which value to take as the correct from duplicated entries.

Answer (score 0):

Although I too didn't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve,  but as you mentioned in the comment, to `create a URL string from a dictionary` , simply use:

```
func urlString() -> String
    {
        var string = ""

        for key in self.keys
        {
            if let value = self[key]
            {
                string += "&\(key)=\(value)"
            }
        }
        return string
    }
```

Comment: yes, i want to add in a URL string. is this working for [[String : Any]] ? or just [String : Any]

Comment: the method you were writing is not working for arrays of dictionaries it's just working for dictionaries

Comment: Yes it converts a dictionary into string. To convert an array of dictionaries, loop through the array and append the corresponding string.